# How to code a Google Analytics virtual pageview on a modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, modal-dialog

The goal is to get statistics when the users go on "modal window"

I am using **Google Tag Manager** and **Google Analytics**. On the static pages i follow the the user with Reporting/Real Time/Content/Active Page. Everything is perfect.

Now here is the issue;
i open a modal window : <**class="modal fade" role="dialog"** ...>
and fire the event:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y');  Firebug show ---> Creating new tracker: t0
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send','pageview','/MyModalPageName');
```

Then on Reporting/Real Time/Content, the Active page field is empty.

Besides, is no error on chrome/ga debugger.

Have you an idea on how to solve this issue ?
Many thanks

Comment: This works, and there shouldn't be any issues. I copy and pasted the last two lines of your code and can see the virtual page name in my real-time view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work well with:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y');
ga('send', { 'hitType': 'pageview', 'page': '/MyModalPageName' });
```